# Removing custom material properties

Tags: materials, scripting

I had to import many FBX files (exported from 3d max) and save them as a blender files and just now realized that all the files also imported custom properties for every objects material.

[image]

I could delete it manually but since its a ton of files with tons of materials i'd prefer to do this by script. However I can't seem to get it to work.

I checked the python code for the custom property and was hoping I could remove it with this line:

```
bpy.ops.wm.properties_remove(data_path="material", property="�L��")
```

But that sadly didn't work. It doesn't understand the "property". I would like the script to be able to run thru all materials in the scene and then delete this (or if possible ANY) custom property for each material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete all custom properties on all the materials in the file with this snippet :

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:  # Iterate over all materials
    props = [*mat.keys()]  # Retrieve custom props names
    for prop in props:
        del mat[prop]
```

Note `*` is the [iterator unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) operator.

Comment: Fantastic, this works like a charm, thank you. But what is the difference with props in mat.keys and wm.properties? Do they access different custom properties?

Comment: `bpy.ops.wm.properties_remove` is an operator. Long story short, this is a construct that is supposed to be used only in the UI when clicking on a button, it is very high level and has a lot of shortcomings, for example it forces a UI redraw everytime it is called. So you really should be using lower-level API whenever you can. `mat.keys` lets you directly get all the custom properties names in a sweep. You can access custom properties with `mat["prop"]` for instance like it was a python dictionary

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)