# Remove all custom properties from bones

Tags: armature, properties, custom-properties

I have an armature that has some bones with custom properties that I don't need. The fact that the armature has a lot of bones and that there a separate properties for edit and pose mode, it would be very difficult to do this manually. Is there any way I can delete all these custom properties all at once?

Comment: With a Python script, you should be able to get rid of the custom properties. You just need to store the properties in a variable before you delete them in a loop, Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253047/107598

Comment: Sorry, but I'm gonna need a bit more of a walkthrough for this. I have no idea how to work with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script. It removes all custom properties that you can define in *Edit* and in *Pose* mode of all bones of the selected armature.

How to run a script is described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194425/107598).

```
import bpy

def ShowMessageBox(message = "", title = "Message Box", icon = 'INFO'):

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text=message)

    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)

 
arm = bpy.context.active_object
    
if arm.type == 'ARMATURE':
    n = 0 
    for bone in arm.data.bones:  # Iterate over all bones
        props = [*bone.keys()]  # Retrieve custom props names
        for prop in props:
            print(f"deleting BONE property {prop}")
            n += 1
            del bone[prop]

    for bone in arm.pose.bones:  # Iterate over all bones
        props = [*bone.keys()]  # Retrieve custom props names
        for prop in props:
            print(f"deleting POSE BONE property {prop}")
            n += 1
            del bone[prop]
    ShowMessageBox(f"deleted {n} custom properties", "INFO", 'INFO')    
        
    
else:
    ShowMessageBox("Please select an armature!", "ERROR", 'ERROR')
```